# Why is "❨╯°□°❩╯︵┻━┻" with such an encoding used for a method name?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I came across following method in [sidekiq gem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq.rb#L29). Its just invoked from [test_sidekiq.rb](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/test/test_sidekiq.rb#L28).

```
def self.❨╯°□°❩╯︵┻━┻
  puts "Calm down, bro"
end
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19851305/1485305) is the only link I was able to find on SO.

1. Google can't understand `❨╯°□°❩╯︵┻━┻`. Why doesn't Ruby complain about this encoding?
2. What is the purpose of this method (not much looking at its body)?
3. Why did author @mike-perham use this name? Just for fun, or testing some boundaries?

Comment: For 2: the source file has this at the top, which specifies the encoding in which these characters for a valid method name: `# encoding: utf-8`

Comment: 5. Maybe he's just bored or very annoyed. As soon as he wanna flip the table, he calls the method and the computer kindly tells him to calm down.

Comment: For 4. I think it's pretty clear [from the unit test](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/test/test_sidekiq.rb#L32): it "allows angry developers to express their emotional constitution and remedies it"

Comment: This is just an easter agg, same as method `forty_two` defined in rails on arrays.

Comment: Don't fret. Believe it or not, some programming languages are actually FUN to program with.

Comment: It _says_ to calm down...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you really do not understand the sense of the method name, that is a (Japanese-style) facemark. Whereas English facemarks are rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise and are long in the vertical direction of the actual face, Japanese facemarks are to be read in the direction as is, and are long in the horizontal direction. The author of this is likely to be either a Japanese, or someone who is influenced by Japanese culture like anime.

In this particular case, each character expresses a certain part. From left to right:

- `❨`   The right edge of the face
- `╯`   The right arm raised
- `°`   The right eye
- `□`   The mouth
- `°`   The left eye
- `❩`   The left edge of the face
- `╯`   The left arm raised
- `︵`   An imaginary curve expressing the trace of a thrown table
- `┻━┻` A thrown upside-down table (most likely a *chabudai* that used to be seen typically in Japanese homes until some decades ago)

[Chabudai gaeshi](https://www.google.com/search?es_sm=93&tbm=isch&q=chabudai+gaeshi&spell=1&sa=X&ei=lXuKU-22Esfh8AWf2ILoDA&ved=0CFMQBSgA&dpr=1&biw=1319&bih=662) used to happen often at some feudal Japanese homes until some decades ago. The father had the absolute monarchic right at home, and whenever he was frustrated over something, he would flip the chabudai during dinner to show his anger, and the family (especially the mother) had to prepare the dinner again.

[image: chabudai gaeshi]

[Here](http://www.facemark.jp/f-chabudai.htm) are more variations.

Comment: Aha! Lol this is good explanation. Now if I could find a way to express myself this way in c...

Comment: Mercifully not many people have used it in gems. Can't imagine learning Japanese to code in Ruby :)

Comment: Lol. Just a nitpick - shouldn't be the description to `╯` symbol **left** *arm raised* in both cases ?

Comment: @DavidUnric No. Both arms are raised.

Answer (score 42):

It's a core part of the Sidekiq API.  Sidekiq is limited to only tables while Sidekiq Pro adds APIs to flip other types of furniture: chairs, ottomans, loveseats, etc.

Comment: OK - we actually bought Sidekiq pro (which we love, btw), but I can't find any additional furniture flipping apis! It's a good thing for you we bought it for the increased reliability on Heroku, and not for the furniture flipping!

Comment: Great marketing 

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the commit that introduced it seems to be some funny sort way to make sure the file is encoded in UTF-8

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/c1127165f8157807e7855c60f9849d20fb9fec24

Comment: That makes sense. It might be a pun on the phrase "flip the table", where table is ambiguous between the physical table and character table.